# The Elif and Else statement is outputting the If statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a basic AI terminal program but when the user says "Name" or something other than "Hi" or "Hello" it outputs "Hi!".

Here is the source code:

```
# Artificial Intelligence Program by KaBoomBox.
# Feel free to edit the source code!

# Importing modules
import time

# Stating basic information
print("AIOSTA Version 0.1.0")
print("Copyleft KaBoomBox \n")

# Asking for name
print("Hello, person.")
name = input("Type in your name before we begin: ")
print("Well thank you,",name ,"! \n")

# Introduction to AI
print("I probably should have told you my name!")
print("My name is AIOSTA.")
print("It stands for Artificially Intelligient Open Source Terminal Assistant.")
print("Anyways, there is not much else to learn about me! \n")

# Chatting
print("Let's talk!")
while True:
    answer = input("Tell me something: ")

    if answer == "Hi" or "hi" or "Hello" or "hi":
        print("Hi! \n")
        time.sleep(1)
    elif answer == "Name" or "name":
        print("My name is AIOSTA, Artificially Intelligient Open Source Terminal Assistant. \n")
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("That is not a viable response.")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `if answer == "Hi" or "hi" or "Hello" or "hi":` is not what you think. Each part between an `or` is evaluated as a boolean, and `"hi"` is always true as a boolean because it's a nonempty string. Try `if answer in ["Hi", "hi", "Hello"]` or use `answer ==` repeatedly for each string you want to test against.

Comment: Thank you ggorlen, that worked!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck.